# Spatial join - allocate values from joined polygon based on input polygon

Tags: qgis, census, flood

I'm trying to determine population inside Special Flood Hazard Areas. To do this I'm doing a spatial join of census shapefiles with the FEMA National Flood Hazard Layer, using the Boolean field SFHA_TF to identify areas inside the Special Flood Hazard Area. The map shows that the SFHA cuts through tracts, taking pieces of some, all of others. But when I join the two tables, the resulting attribute table contains multiple copies of the entire tract; it does not split the tract into pieces (for example a quarter of the tract if the SFHA occupies 1/4 of the tract). Is there a way in QGIS to do a spatial join between two polygons that will get proportionate shares of the joined polygon? 
.[image: Adding screenshot to respond to comment -- green lines are census tracts; orange areas are flood zones]

Comment: A screen shot would sure help me visualize your problem.

Comment: I added an image to answer your comment: Green lines are census tracts, red lines are highways, and orange fill areas are flood zones. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin which provides markedly different functionality to the stock standard VECTOR | INTERSECTION (or did you use spatial join??) [detailed here](https://gisforthought.com/qgis-select-within-plugin/) and available via the standard plugin menu.

Not too sure what your end product is intended to be...